# Multitasking tcp server Async?

Tags: c#, multitasking

**Accepting the client** `Start` function will run only starting...and never ends

```
void Start(){
StartListening();//when the server starting
}
void StartListening(){
server.BeginAcceptTcpClient (AcceptTcpClient,server);
}
void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult ar){
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
        clients.Add (new ServerClient (listener.EndAcceptTcpClient (ar)));
        StartListening ();
    }
```

**Listening the clients**`Update` function will run for each milliseconds.

```
void Update(){   foreach (ServerClient c in clients.ToList()) {
            //is the client still connected
                if (!isConnected (c.tcp)) {
                    c.tcp.Close ();
                    disconnectList.Add (c);
                    continue;
                } else { 
                    NetworkStream s = c.tcp.GetStream ();
                    if(s.DataAvailable){
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (s,true);
                        string data = reader.ReadLine ();
                        if (data != null)
                            OnIncomingData (c,data);                                        
                    }
                }
            }}
```

It is not fully code but I think it's enough for understanding my question.The question is Can that server code handle multiple clients at the same time? ..or it will freeze when connecting or receiving from a server.

**P.S**

```
 private bool isConnected(TcpClient c){
        try{
            if(c!=null && c.Client!=null && c.Client.Connected){
                if(c.Client.Poll(0,SelectMode.SelectRead)){
                    return !(c.Client.Receive(new byte[1],SocketFlags.Peek)==0);
                }
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;}
        }
        catch {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just simply run it and try? But it looks like the `update` function is written as a blocking function, and will thus block until data is actually received.

Comment: "will run only starting...and never ends" - can you clarify what you mean here? what is "starting..."? does it accept the connection, i.e. get as far as `clients.Add(...)` ? What is running `Update()` ? Is this a binary protocol, or a text protocol? The implementation is dangerous, note: I could stall your server simply by sending "a" without a line-ending and keeping the socket open. There's also a very good chance that you'd drop data regularly - `StreamReader` has a *buffer* that may be *oversized* - i.e. it doesn't read from the inputstream byte-by-byte until it finds a CRLF

Comment: @fredrik I am trying and it is runnig well but I cannot test it in more than ten clients.

Comment: I'd be interested in the implementation of `isConnected` ...

Comment: _"The question is Can that server code handle multiple clients at the same time?"_ - No. It _could_ handle multiple clients _sequentially_.

Comment: @Fildor I added `isConnected`

Comment: @Marc Gravell  So I just have to add to `clients.Add(...)` for checking `TcpListener` not to be the same value

Comment: @AsssaaHJiok I don't understand what you just said at all, but it sounds like something is working ("I am trying and it is runnig well")  so: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Fildor or it could handle exactly one evil person like me who would send "mwahah" without a CRLF and leave the socket open forever :) I jest, but there's a serious point here for Asssaa's benefit: every client is malicious, and even innocent clients send incomplete frames because they went through a tunnel at the wrong time.. `ReadLine()` has **no place** in a TCP server *ever*

Comment: Am I have to add a new `Thread` or `AsyncState` is enough?

Comment: @AsssaaHJiok you haven't told us what problem you're trying to solve; multi-threaded many-client TCP servers are non-trivial, and I hate to say it but the single-threaded version here is already pretty bad (note: you've already missed the list synchronization, and that `ReadLine` is deadly) - I'm very worried that if you add even more threads, you're going to dig yourself even deeper into a hole *very very quickly*. Now: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ Marc Gravell you just said all my problems. So can you give some links for security  or productivity

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a notification because of the space between @ and Marc. How many clients do you need to support? This matters. How you build a TCP server that needs to handle 20 clients is very different to how to do it when you need to handle 20,000 clients. Or 500,000.  What is the volume and pattern of requests? But: this stuff is *really really hard* to do well. The new "pipelines" project should simplify a lot of this, but that is some way away yet.

Comment: @Marc Gravell I need to handle about 20,000 clients and every clients should get request each 2-3 seconds.Can you show me a few  "pipelines" projects or library ?

Comment: @AsssaaHJiok I'm going to be honest - based on the code in the question: I think that this requirement is far above your current skillset and sockets experience. That level of scalability is *really hard* to do well, and involves in-depth knowledge of things like buffer pools, async IO, synchronization, etc. The "pipelines" work is in "corefxlab", and is *brutally* incomplete and moving rapidly - you don't want to touch that right now; maybe in 6-12 months. There are frameworks that might help you here, maybe: "NetGain" or "SimplSockets".

Comment: @AsssaaHJiok additional thought: 20k is also reaching the number where you need to worry about ephemeral port exhaustion; I run the custom socket-server that drives the realtime live updates here on SO - we run about 60k connections per server process (for a total of 500k+ live sockets), but we need to spread that 60k over multiple listener ports (proxied by a NLB), otherwise hard various limits (in both Windows and the linux socket layers) start causing problems.

Comment: @AsssaaHJiok oh, you'd also need *much better* frame testing/processing logic - to avoid the ReadLine problem that I brought up here; and a working knowledge of back-buffers, etc. Note: all of these complexities are things that "pipelines" aims to make **much, much simpler**, but: it isn't ready today. Folks at MS - with input from a few network folks like myself - are working on it. It is very hard to make efficient network code look simple to the consumer :)